# How to correctly incorporate JQuery into an Azure Function?

Tags: jquery, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I want to use JQuery within an Azure Function to process some JSON Data (with $.getJSON) and iterate through the response.  I realise that I could re-write this using plain Javascript, but I was hoping to just recycle some old JQuery code.

I've run `npm install jquery` using the Kudu console, and I've read in the JQuery docs about how it recommends using '[jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)' as a helper to provide a window to an otherwise windowless environment.  I've ran `npm install jsdom` but I am unsure if my function is formatted correctly (this function uses [the jsdom sample code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery#node) from the JQuery docs):

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');



    if (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name)) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name)
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
    context.done();
};
```

Has anyone successfully used JQuery within an Azure Function?  Or is that not recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is written aginst [XMLHttpRequest (XHR)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Natively Node.js does not provide the browser XHR API.

If the file is on the server itself, you can use the [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) or [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options).

If it is on a remote server, then you can do an asynchronous XHR type request using a module like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). For example:

```
request({
  url: 'http://...',
  json: true
}, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```